# Another bluetooth problem Ubuntu 18.04 cannot find adaptor at all

Tags: bluetooth

I've got an issue on my Lenovo Yoga 900 that has degraded to an unusable point...  My bluetooth adaptor is now consistently unable to be detected by ubuntu and I can't use my mouse anymore.  Running `blueman-manager` returns `connection to Bluez  failed, Bluez daemon not running` and by all indications it seems the adaptor is just not found.

I run Win10 off a Live USB and can confirm the bluetooth hardware works fine at any time.

The bluetooth used to detect the adaptor and pair with my mouse perfectly fine, for over a year.  It has recently begun to sometimes boot up without detecting the adaptor and usually a logout/login fixed it.  That no longer works.  It now fails to detect it throughout restarts, etc.

I managed to get it working for a day, by purging and removing `bluez` and `blueman` via `apt-get` - however, Even though I did it a few times, it only worked when I also wiped bluetooth via `dkpg` before reinstalling it with `apt-get`

.

- rfkill output

```
 0 wlan      ideapad_wlan      unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth ideapad_bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      phy0              unblocked unblocked
```

- dmesg | grep -i bluetooth output

- lspci | grep -i bluetooth output

- lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 42)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:1130]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

- lsusb output

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2f68:0082  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

- If I can force the blueman-manager applet to load with trickery, all options on it are greyed out
- running bluetoothd returns D-bus service failed to start, due to security policy not allowing it, running with sudo runs it but it freezes and has to be ctrl-c broken out of
- running bluetoothctl just freezes it and has to be ctrl-c killed
- forcing the service to stop/restart/start with service or /etc/init.d/bluetooth seems to do nothing (It says service stop/start successful, but no adaptor shows up)
- sudo service bluetooth status returns : Loaded and enabled, but Active : inactive (dead)

I had not upgraded my kernel, and found reports of it not finding the adaptor due to a bug in a version of the kernel, so I upgraded my kernel, and it didn't fix the problem.
uname -a = 4.15.0-76-generic

I'm quite annoyed.  Can anyone help?

EDIT : It just spontanously turned on by itself (after several hours of not working) I am sure it will break again next system restart.

I'll now paste all the info again now, to show what is different.

rfkill shows a new bluetooth device

```
 0 wlan      ideapad_wlan      unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth ideapad_bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      phy0              unblocked unblocked
 3 bluetooth hci0              unblocked unblocked <-- this is new
```

dmesg now shows bluetooth information (blank before)

```
[ 6575.123122] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 6575.123220] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 6575.124820] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 6575.124823] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 6575.124830] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 6575.139752] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[ 6575.145763] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[ 6575.145764] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[ 6575.145765] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[ 6575.145766] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[ 6575.145766] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[ 6575.145767] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[ 6575.147823] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[ 6575.212974] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 6575.212976] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 6575.212978] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 6576.578303] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[ 6576.578740] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1409555 usecs
[ 6576.578803] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[ 6576.589742] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 10717 usecs
[ 6576.591029] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[ 6576.595754] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[ 6576.645563] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 6576.645568] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 6576.645572] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 7795.057216] hid-generic 0005:046D:B015.000D: input,hidraw5: BLUETOOTH HID v0.07 Keyboard [M720 Triathlon] on E4:B3:18:AC:BB:78
```

output of lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Graphics 540 (rev 0a)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:15.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #3 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 42)
02:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8620 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM951/PM951 (rev 01)
```

sudo service bluetooth status  output

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-02-02 16:25:01 GMT; 29min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 7765 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─7765 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Feb 02 16:45:21 Yoga bluetoothd[7765]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Feb 02 16:45:21 Yoga bluetoothd[7765]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Feb 02 16:45:21 Yoga bluetoothd[7765]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Feb 02 16:45:21 Yoga bluetoothd[7765]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Feb 02 16:45:21 Yoga bluetoothd[7765]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Feb 02 16:45:21 Yoga bluetoothd[7765]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Feb 02 16:45:21 Yoga bluetoothd[7765]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Feb 02 16:45:21 Yoga bluetoothd[7765]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Feb 02 16:45:21 Yoga bluetoothd[7765]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
Feb 02 16:45:21 Yoga bluetoothd[7765]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
```

lsusb output

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2f68:0082  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5664 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

EDIT 2:

It seems the only way to get it working at the moment when it breaks it to completely remove it and purge all configuration files.

I Removed everything with `apt remove bluez*` and `apt remove blueman*` then this seems to be the important step - `dpkg --purge bluez` and `blueman` which removes all configuration files.  I went through the system, trying to find any and all bluetooth modules to remove them.  Ran update and upgrade, autoremove.

I rebooted to ensure everything was out of memory, then reinstalled only apt install blueman - it installs 3 packages only.  Ill leave it at the minimum for now.

It has worked across one reboot, hopefully it holds.  It takes the system half a minute to 'detect' the bluetooth adaptor however, after booting up.  I think it's detecting it twice, somehow (two adaptors in rfkill)

EDIT 3 : BROKEN AGAIN !!

The above process is not working to restore it.

I tried to run the bluetooth service with systemd and monitored it with journalctl.  It outputs this

```
bluetoothd[1013]: Bluetooth management 1.14 interface initialized
bluetoothd[1013]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
bluetoothd[1013]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
bluetoothd[1013]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
(repeat about 20 times)
bluetoothd[1013]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
bluetoothd[1013]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
bluetoothd[1013]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoi nt/A2DPSink
bluetoothd[1013]: Terminating
```

I've attempted to update iwlwifi drivers from a backport repository (the only iwlwifi repository I could find.  It automatically builds a driver when you install from it though. I used this procedure

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

I don't know if that helped yet.

It seems that the bluetooth adaptor (when working) is actually on an usb attachment point.

```
              *-usb:1
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

Yet the system thinks there's one on the wifi card - the 8260.  The cards configuration settings state it runs in dual mode with `bt_coex_active=1`. I will try to change this setting to 0 somehow to see if it correctly detects the seprate BT usb peripheral.

EDIT 423 :  I've confirmed it is related to the USB system.  For some reason the USB system does not recognize the bluetooth adaptor upon startup.  I can force it to update by plugging and unplugging the power USB  ( Lenovo power cord goes into the USB ) and my keyboard USB - then it gets the bluetooth turned on after a bit.

Is there a way to reinstall usb drivers?  What are the USB drivers called?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+C to copy form a terminal.

Comment: The device works. Something else in user space is wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  The device works.  But something is making Ubuntu ignore it.  I am here to try to find out what that thing is.  I have tried to include as much information as I can and hope others have some insight that I don't have.

Comment: `bt_coex_active=1` is default and it is not relevant. This setting is to solve problems with simulteneous use, like sound drope, etc. It won't affect anything like work or not. `iwlwifi` won't affect BT either. And it is correct that BT is attached to USB.